# Get byte - how is this wrong?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I want to get the designated byte from a 32 bit integer. I am getting wrong values but I don't know why.

The restrictions to this problem are:

- Must use signed bits, and I can't use multiplication.
- I specifically need to know what is wrong with the function as it's below.

Here is the function:

```
int retrieveByteFromWord(int word, int byte)
{
  return (word >> (byte << 3)) & 0xFF;
}
```

ex:
           (3)       (2)      (1)      (0)      ------ byte number
In word: 10010011 11001100 00110011 10101000

I want to return byte 2 (1100 1100).

`retrieveByteFromWord(word, 2)` ---- gives: 1100 1100

But for some cases it's wrong and it won't tell me what case.

Any ideas?

---

Here is the problem:

You just started working for a company that is implementing a set of procedures to operate on a data structure where 4 signed bytes are packed into a 32 bit unsigned. Bytes within the word are numbered from 0(LSB) to 3(MSB). You have been assigned the task of implementing a function for a machine using 2's complement arithmetic and arithmetic right shifts with the following prototype:

```
typedef unsigned packed_t

int xbyte(packed_t word, int bytenum);
```

This is the previous employees attempt which got him fired for being wrong:

```
int xbyte(packed_t word, int bytenum)
{
  return (word >> (bytenum << 3)) & 0xFF;
}
```

- A) What is wrong with the code?
- B) Write a correct implementation using only left and right shifts and one subtraction.

I have done B but still don't know why A is wrong. Is it because the decimal numbers going in like 12, 15, 19, 55 and then getting packed into a word and then when I extract them they aren't the same number anymore??? It might be so I am going to run some tests real fast...

Comment: How can we know it is wrong if you don't explain what it is supposed to do? Include some examples of input and expected output.

Comment: On my VS2008 this code works as expected. It extracts a byte within given `word` on position given by `byte` (0 is LSB, 3 is MSB).

Comment: -1 no description of what the "wrong values" are.

Comment: Im expecting that since I and with 0xFF that in a case I am going to erase a bit or keep a bit set when it should be reset but I cant find a specific one.

Comment: If I knew what the wrong values are I would be able to fix it wouldn't I???

Comment: "must use signed" and "can't use multiplication" is meaningless.

Comment: @Alf, not meaningless, considering it's homework. If I'm not mistaking the goal of the homework seems to be exactly to find that corner case where the function fails.

Comment: It was to another answer that isnt there anymore.

Comment: What is the 2nd byte in the value `-1 (11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111)`? Is it `-1`, `255`, some error value? ???

Comment: @Adam: The question has changed since I commented. You were the one changing the question. Sorry, I had to flag your insult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is homework I won't give you a full answer, but I'll point you in the right direction. Your problem statement says that:

> 4 **signed** bytes are packed into a 32 bit unsigned.

When you bitwise `&` a 32 bit signed integer with 0xFF the most significant bit - i.e. the *sign* bit - of the result is always `0`, so the original function never returns a negative value regardless of the input.

---

By way of example...

When you say "retrieveByteFromWord(word, 2) ---- gives: 11001100" you're wrong.

Your return type is a 32 bit integer - not an 8 bit integer. You're not returning `11001100` you're returning `00000000 00000000 00000000 11001100`.

Answer (score 3):

To work with *numbers*, use signed integer types such as `int`.

To work with *bits*, use unsigned integer types such as `unsigned`. I.e. let the `word` argument be of type `unsigned`. That is what the unsigned types are for.

To multiply by 8, write just `*8` (this does not mean that that part of the code is technically wrong, just that it is artificially contrived and needlessly unreadable).

Even better, create a self-describing name for that magic number 8, e.g. `*bitsPerByte` (the standard library calls it `CHAR_BIT`, which is not particularly self-describing nor readable).

Finally, at the design level, think about designing your functions so that the code that uses a function of yours – each *call* – becomes clear and readable. E.g. like `int const b = byteAt( 2, x );`. That can prevent bugs by e.g. preventing wrong actual argument order, and since designing for readability makes the code easier to read, it reduces time spent on that. :-)

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I vote for calling it `bitsPerOctet` so the futility of trying to eliminate magic numbers becomes more apparent. :-)

Comment: @R.: the reason the standard library uses `CHAR_BIT` is that it's not always 8. On some systems it's 16 (e.g., Texas Instruments DSP).

Comment: The question has changed a lot since I wrote the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for positive numbers. You may want to cast `word` to unsigned to make it work for integers with the MSB set.

```
int retrieveByteFromWord(int word, int byte)
{
  return ((unsigned)word >> (byte << 3)) & 0xFF;
}
```